# JSON Nested Ul from single or multidimensional json object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I found this cool script http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=67767 that will be solving a lot of headed for the project I am working on, basically the script takes a json and renders the data on a nice ul, so the script from the url is parsing the json after you paste the data on the textarea and the you click:

```
<button onclick="$('#output').html(json_tree(JSON.parse($('#json').val())));">Build Tree</button>
```

I need to modify this script to render the Ul on load, but I am having a hard time understanding how to make it work, i created a jsfiddle at the following url: https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/2urxusmy/3/

This is how the Js looks like:

```
var data = {
            "level_0": [
                {
                    "level_0_name": "Americas",
                    "level_0_id": 1,
                    "level_1": [
                        {
                            "level_1_name": "CompanySanJoseEBC",
                            "level_1_id": 12345,
                            "level_2": [
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "MinistryOfDefense",
                                    "level_2_id": 2451,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Andy Schutz",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Overall Experience",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Vijay Venugopal",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "SomeEvent1",
                                    "level_2_id": 3333,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 235
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "BAC ABC",
                                            "id": 354
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "XUY XUY",
                                            "id": 876
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "SomeOtherEvent",
                                    "level_2_id": 2345,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 357
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "YTE",
                                            "id": 176
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Mary B",
                                            "id": 267
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "level_0_name": "APJ",
                    "level_1": [
                        {
                            "level_1_name": "CompanySingaporeEBC",
                            "level_2": [
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "Khoo Tech Puat",
                                    "level_2_id": 2222,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Xyx asd",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "What to do in Barcelona",
                                    "level_2_id": 2356,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Xyx asd",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "Visiting in Barcelona",
                                    "level_2_id": 27534,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Xyx asd",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "level_0_name": "Asia",
                    "level_1": [
                        {
                            "level_1_name": "CompanyLondonEBC",
                            "level_2": [
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "Living in Beijing",
                                    "level_2_id": 2367,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Xyx asd",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "What to do in Beijing",
                                    "level_2_id": 5678,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Xyx asd",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "level_2_name": "Visiting in Beijing",
                                    "level_2_id": 2789,
                                    "level_3": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "John Doe",
                                            "id": 123
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Xyx asd",
                                            "id": 456
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                                            "id": 789
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }


        function json_tree(object) {
        var json="<ul>";
        for(prop in object){
            var value = object[prop];
            switch (typeof(value)){
                case "object":
                var token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,16);
                        json += "<li><a class='label' href='#"+token+"' data-toggle='collapse'>"+prop+"="+value+"</a><div id='"+token+"' class='collapse'>"+json_tree(value)+"</div></li>";
                        break;
                        default:
                        json += "<li>"+prop+"="+value+"</li>";
                    }
                }
                return json+"</ul>";
            } 

        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Append json data to output container
            $('#output').html(json_tree(JSON.parse($('data').val())));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function json_tree(object) {
var json="<ul>";
for(prop in object){
    var value = object[prop];
    switch (typeof(value)){
        case "object":
        var token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,16);
                json += "<li><a class='label' href='#"
                     +token+"' data-toggle='collapse'>"
                     +prop+"="+value+"</a><div id='"+token+"' class='collapse'>"
                     +json_tree(value)+"</div></li>";
            default:
                json += "<li>"+prop+"="+value+"</li>";
                break;

            }

        }
        return json+"</ul>"; 
    } 

$(document).ready(function() {        
    // call `json_tree` with `data` as object argument ,
    //Append json data to output container
    $('#output').html(json_tree(data));
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2urxusmy/2/

Comment: Any ideas of how to remove the objects labels like [level_0=[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]] from the tree and keep only values from the list? @gues271314